# Textbox line counter (more complex) VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, textbox

im deep into (for fun and learning) programming and i have problem,
i know how to count lines in textbox with this simple code

```
Label1.Text = Textbox1.Lines.Count
```

But this code doesnt count lines when i paste some multiline text it count it as one line.
And yes, one more question is there way to make line counter live,
i tried

```
    Private Sub Textbox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Page_Names.TextChanged
Label1.Text = Textbox1.Lines.Count
End Sub
```

but this reproduce much lag.

Example of "Multiline" text that i want to paste

```
email1@gmail.com
email2@gmail.com
email3@gmail.com
email4@gmail.com
email5@gmail.com
email6@gmail.com
email7@gmail.com
email8@gmail.com
email9@gmail.com
email10@gmail.com
email11@gmail.com
```

Sorry for stupid question im new, and sorry for bad English :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The `Lines` property of a `TextBox` is unaffected by word wrap.  If you have long text that wraps but contains no line breaks then `Lines.Count` will be 1.

Comment: WordWrap = false on my textbox, i tried for example to copy proxy list there and still get only 1 as result

Comment: can we know what's the mutiline text ?

Comment: More than one line, thats what i mean, sorry for bad english again

Comment: for example list of email subscribers from my website

Comment: i mean what is that string you're trying to deal with? show me that string

Comment: I edited my post

Comment: Try looping through the .text value of the textbox and count the number of vb.cr or vb.crlf in it. You may need to add 1 to the result if the last line doesnt have one.

Comment: i tried it and it shows  11 lines? can you please post a screenshot where it doesn't show correct count

Comment: It works when counting lines by button, but i want to make it live

Comment: Your code works and shows the correct count of lines.

Comment: `TextBox1_TextChanged` works fine tho

Answer (score 0):

Due to lower reputation I was unabled to answer it in the add comment section, thus posted it here.
The solution for your problem is to play with the textbox properties. Change the AcceptReturn Property to true of the textbox properties.

Multiline=true
AcceptReturn=true
then you can do anything to count the lines of the textbox.
just like adding a button, a label and then adding codes like to button clicking event.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Label1.Text = TextBox1.Lines.Count
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You handle a different TextBox's TextChanged Event that the one you want to count the lines of.

Try this:

```
Private Sub Textbox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Textbox1.TextChanged
Label1.Text = Textbox1.Lines.Count
End Sub
```